# Perl Supress Saveas Dialog using Word OLE

Tags: perl, dialog, ole

I have a perl script that I am running which uses Microsoft Word OLE and runs spellcheck against the conent I pass to it. I am running into a problem as I am not saving a file or document so when i try and quit word, it wants me to save something (Prompt Save As).

I need to be able to supress this message or trick the document into thinking it was already saved. Is this possible or can you think of another solution?

I tried DisplayAlerts = 0 and that didnt seem to help either.

```
sub LaunchSpellcheck
{
#Check the version to see if there are updates.
checkVersion();

#Open up MS Word and only display the spellcheck box.
my $Word = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Word.Application') || Win32::OLE->new('Word.Application');
my @windows = FindWindowLike(undef,"Microsoft Word","");
SetActiveWindow(@windows[0]);
$Word->{'Visible'} = 0;

#Add a new document in word
my $TmpDocument = $Word->Documents->Add();
$TmpDocument = $TmpDocument->{Content};
#Add contents of clipboard to document
$TmpDocument ->{Text} = $clipboard->GetText();

#Check the spelling
$Word->ActiveDocument->CheckSpelling;
#Set the content of the file back to the clipboard.
$clipboard->Set($TmpDocument ->{Text});

#Hide save as dialog
$Word->{'DisplayAlerts'} = 0;
$Word->Quit;

MessageBox('The spellchecked content has been saved to your clipboard.','Spellcheck Complete');

#Log that the tool was used to the global log.
TrackUsage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
my $Word = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Word.Application') || Win32::OLE->new('Word.Application');
$Word->{'DisplayAlerts'} = 0;
....
```